# getElementById Button not opening virtual window onclick

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, onclick, getelementbyid

I need a window to open a login page as a virtual window when the button is clicked, and the window isn't opening

I don't know how to fix this at all, i'm not very experienced in JS at all, and I did not write the original code, i had paid someone to do it.

```
<button type="button" class="button black login"
 href="#myModal" data-backdrop="false" data-toggle="modal" 
onClick='document.getElementById("fwindow").src="login.html";'>
<span>Sign in with Steam</span> <i class="fa fa-steam" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </button>
```

I expect the window to open, and it does not.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `onClick='document.getElementById("fwindow").src="login.html";'` by `onClick="location.href = 'login.html'"` and it will work .

Comment: i need it to open in an i frame, this simply redirects to the page